# Powershell how to add new line after certain string

Tags: powershell, newline

I am very new to scripting. I am trying to solve one problem and I was looking at windows batch and powershell. I have found this but I dont know, why it is not working:

I have input.txt file with this content:

```
<a> TEXT </a>
<c> text asdrtlj </c>
<a> another text </a>
```

I want to add new line before every `<a>`, so I tried this:

```
powershell -Command "(gc input.txt) -replace '<a>', '`r`n<a>' | Out-File output.txt"
```

That adding of newline doesnt work. Can you help me please?

PS: I've found a lot of complicated codes while searching the solution and I haven't understood them yet so if you recommend me some good tutorials where to start with this languages I will appreciate it.

Comment: For learning PowerShell I'd recommend the [learn windows powershell in a month of lunches](https://www.manning.com/books/learn-windows-powershell-in-a-month-of-lunches-second-edition) book.

Answer (score 5):

There are a couple of issues here. Executing a command via the `-command` switch of powershell is causing some reserved character issues due to the < > characters.

Instead, open a PowerShell.exe window (start -> run -> powershell) and execute the command directly.

You also need to use double quotes not single quotes in order for special codes like `r and `n to work. Also `n should be sufficient on its own:

```
(gc input.txt) -replace '<a>', "`n<a>" | Out-File output.txt
```

Comment: [about_quoting_rules](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules) helps explain single and double quotes and also how escape them.

Comment: _causing some reserved character issues due to the < > characters._ What does that mean? The only issue I see here is the single quotes and quoting in general?

Comment: `powershell -Command "(gc input.txt) -replace '<a>', ""`r`n<a>"" | Out-File output.txt"` results in: `The '<' operator is reserved for future use.`

Comment: This solution works. But I just want to run file "run.cmd". I use type *.xml | findstr ... to preprare my input file and than I am trying to use powershell. I can't run it from strat->run-> powerrshell. So I am fighting single and double quotes and escaping them. I will read article from James C., hope it will help.

Answer (score 2):

We need more quotation marks.

```
powershell.exe -command "(gc 1_105.jpg) -replace '<a>', """"`r`n<a>""""|Out-File output.txt"
```

Or how is about a small refactoring?

```
powershell.exe -Command "gc input.txt|%{$_.replace('<a>',[environment]::newline+'<a>')}|Out-File output.txt"
```

Comment: Solution with more quotation works fine, thank you. And what about, if I want to replace more strings in one step. Something like this:
powershell -Command "(Get-Content input) | Foreach-Object { $_ -replace '<a>', '<aaaa>' ` -replace '</b>', '</bbb>'} | Out-File output1.txt"
I need to escape ` but don't know how. :/

Comment: What do you use a backquote for? Try replace that with a pair of brackets: `powershell.exe -c "gc 1_105.jpg|%{($_ -replace '<rdf:Alt>','<ALT:RDF>') -replace '</rdf:li>','</LI:RDF>'}|sc out.txt"`. Or do it with an one call of the replace method of [regex]: `powershell.exe -c "gc 1_105.jpg|%{[regex]::replace($_,'<rdf:Alt>|</rdf:li>',{param($g)@{'<rdf:Alt>'='<ALT:RDF>';'</rdf:li>'='</LI:RDF>'}[$g.value]})}|sc out.txt"`.